# duplicate connects in a signal/slot system

Tags: c++, lambda

I'd like to detect duplicate `connect`s to a signal in a signal/slot system, for example, when doing this:

```
button.connect("onClicked", [this](){ do_something(); });
button.connect("onClicked", [this](){ do_something(); });
```

when slot is a function pointer, an (instance_ptr, memfun_ptr) pair, or even a functor having `operator==()` defined, comparing slots is possible and hence it is possible to detect duplicate `connect`s, but lambda objects are not comparable. What workarounds to this problem exist? I was thinking about giving slots a name as well and compare slots on the basis of that name:

```
button.connect("onClicked", "handleConnect", [this](){ do_something(); });
```

But maybe I should simply ban lambda functors as slots?

Comment: Are you talking about a generic "signal/slot" system, or some specific system (like Qt)?

Comment: generic, i.e. home-made signal/slot system.

Comment: Then simply design around the problem. Simply storing functions in a vector (or other collection, using e.g. `std::function`) for a single slot, and then on "signal" call all the functions in the collection seems to be one way to solve it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg for a single slot? Maybe write an answer? How can I identify a single slot? I'd like a `::std::set`, instead of a `::std::vector`, but I need `operator==` and a hash function for that. I'd be satisfied with an `operator==`.

Comment: If the user of the signal/slot system adds the same function (doesn't matter if it's a function pointer, `std::function` object, a lambda or something else) then I think the problem is on the users side and not yours as the signal/slot implementer. And who says that the user might not have a valid use-case for duplicate functions in a slot (due to side-effects or something)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Certainly, but if you check the `Qt` implementation, it checks for this and ignores the duplicate `connect`. I think this does not work with lambda objects though.